# Отправка фото в телеграм. Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram

Моя задача - отправить пользователю картинки, которые я успешно спарсил и добавил в папку. Теперь эти фотографии нужно отправить через телеграм-бота. А я не знаю, как их достать из папки.
Вот код

```
import telebot
import requests
from lxml import html

bot = telebot.TeleBot('api')


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text:


        name = message.text
        t = requests.get(f'https://wttr.in/{name}?format=4').text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, t)

       
        url = f'https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/{name}'
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        a = [x.attrib['src'] for x in tree.cssselect('img') if 'png' in x.attrib['src'] or 'jpg' in x.attrib['src']]
        for pic_link in a[:3]:
            with open('test/' + pic_link.split('/')[-1], 'wb') as f:
                f.write(requests.get('http:'+pic_link).content)


bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Попробуйте модуль `glob`: `from glob import glob`, и поиск картинок, будет примерно так: `images = glob('test/*.jpg') + glob('test/*.png')`

Answer (score 0):

1. Вынесите парсинг в отдельную функцию - код станет чище и понятнее.
2. Для задач, требующих длительного ввода/вывода, используйте `asyncio` (т.е. замените `telebot` на [aiogram](https://github.com/aiogram/aiogram)), либо используйте отдельный поток. В вашем кейсе 4 пользователя смогут **полностью заблокировать вам бота** (все "воркеры" будут заняты скачиванием).
3. Делайте проверки от обратного, чтобы не растить лестницу в коде. Хотя конкретно в вашем случае проверка наличия `message.text` избыточна, её можно убрать.
4. Вот пример асинхронной отправки изображения:

```py
@dp.message_handler()
async def cats(message: Message):
    with open('cats.jpg', 'rb') as photo:
        await message.reply_photo(photo, caption='Cats are here ')
```